# JQuery .ajax dont call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, function-call

I have object "game" and when i call create game, its use jquery ajax... everything works ok, but when i want to call from ajax success function addLoadEvent it doesnt call it, when i try call this function from createGame (commented part of code here) its works... do you know why i cant call it from ajax success? i try console log from success and it was print in console so ajax works well. Thank everybody for help

```
        var game=new ttt_game();
        function addLoadEvent(func) {
            var oldonload = window.onload;
            if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
                window.onload = func;
            } else {
                window.onload = function() {
                    if (oldonload) {
                        oldonload();
                    }
                    func();
                }
            }
        }            
        function ttt_game () {
            this.createGame = createGame;

            function createGame(){
                /*addLoadEvent(function(){
                            document.getElementById('player1_n').textContent=player1+':';
                            document.getElementById('player2_n').textContent=player2+':';
                            document.getElementById('turn').textContent='Čaká sa na príchod súpera.';
                        });*/
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process.php",
                    data: {'function': 'create','game_id': game_id,'player1': player1},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                        addLoadEvent(function(){
                            document.getElementById('player1_n').textContent=player1+':';
                            document.getElementById('player2_n').textContent=player2+':';
                            document.getElementById('turn').textContent='Čaká sa na príchod súpera.';
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
        } 
        game.createGame();
```

Comment: did you check whether the `success` handler is called? also check your browser console to see whether there is any error

Comment: Ok... it looks like on `addLoadEvent`, you are adding a `window.onload()` handler, this works when you call from `createGame` when when it is called the `window.onload` is not yet fired but when you are calling it from the success handler the `onload` event might have already fired because the ajax is processed asynchronously

Comment: @ArunPJohny its silly :) you are right 'window.onload' was fired and when i try it on success outside function 'addLoadEvent' its works but yesterday when i code it... it doesnt work and i must use this function 'addLoadEvent' because html elements was not create :)
thank you for help

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like on `addLoadEvent`, you are adding a `window.onload` handler, this works when you call from `createGame` when when it is called the `window.onload` is not yet fired but when you are calling it from the success handler the onload event might have already fired because the ajax is processed asynchronously